# Is there a classification task with multiple attribute regression?

Tags: classification, regression, supervised-learning

I'm trying to look for a task that predicts a discrete label first (classification), and then predicts the multiple continuous attributes of the predicted class. I found some papers about [multi-output regression](http://oa.upm.es/40804/1/INVE_MEM_2015_204213.pdf), but it wasn't what I wanted. Perhaps such a task exists in robot control or in video games, but I haven't found it yet. At the same time I want to train within a supervised learning framework, not reinforcement learning.

Comment: Hi and welcome to AI SE! Can you explain a little bit why you first need to predict a class and then predict attributees of that class? Maybe the context can also be helpful.